# Expand dataframe in R by columns having different ID values

Tags: r, subset, tidyverse

I have the following data frame in R

```
df1 <- data.frame(
    "ID" = c("A", "B", "A", "B"),
    "Value" = c(1, 2, 5, 5),
    "freq" = c(1, 3, 5, 3)
)
```

I wish to obtain the following data frame

```
     Value      freq  ID
      1           1    A
      2          NA    A 
      3          NA    A
      4          NA    A
      5          1     A
      1          NA    B
      2          2     B 
      3          NA    B
      4          NA    B
      5          5     B
```

I have tried the following code

```
library(tidyverse)
df_new <- bind_cols(df1 %>%
                        select(Value, freq, ID) %>%
                        complete(., expand(., 
                                     Value = min(df1$Value):max(df1$Value))),)
```

I am getting the following output

```
   Value  freq ID   
 <dbl> <dbl> <fct>
 1     1     A    
 2     3     B    
 3     NA    NA   
 4     NA    NA   
 5     5     A    
 5     3     B
```

I request someone to help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1) 
setkey(df1, ID, Value)

df1[CJ(ID = c("A", "B"), Value = 1:5)]

    ID Value freq
 1:  A     1    1
 2:  A     2   NA
 3:  A     3   NA
 4:  A     4   NA
 5:  A     5    5
 6:  B     1   NA
 7:  B     2    3
 8:  B     3   NA
 9:  B     4   NA
10:  B     5    3
```

Comment: what does the CJ refer to.

Comment: Cross join: Just try to run `CJ(ID = c("A", "B"), Value = 1:5)` separately. It's like expand.grid in base R.

Answer (score 4):

Using `tidyr::full_seq` we can find the full version of `Value` but `nesting(full_seq(Value,1)` will return an error:

> Error: `by` can't contain join column `full_seq(Value, 1)` which is missing from RHS

so we need to add a name, hence `nesting(Value=full_seq(Value,1)`

```
library(tidyr)
df1 %>% complete(ID, nesting(Value=full_seq(Value,1)))

# A tibble: 10 x 3
  ID    Value  freq
  <fct> <dbl> <dbl>
  1 A        1.    1.
  2 A        2.   NA 
  3 A        3.   NA 
  4 A        4.   NA 
  5 A        5.    5.
  6 B        1.   NA 
  7 B        2.    3.
  8 B        3.   NA 
  9 B        4.   NA 
 10 B        5.    3.
```

Comment: But if you take a look at row 5 it's different from desired output. Maybe it's a typo. Very nice approach though

Comment: @patL I think there is a typo in the desired output *or* the `freq` is calculated but the original post does not provide enough detail at the moment.

Comment: Yeah. I tought the same, but I wanted to point it out just in case.

Comment: @patL I checked it before I post my answer and its probably a type since `freq=c(1,3,5,3)`.

Comment: @A.Suliman That's what I thought when I was trying to answer to the question. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Would the following approach work for you?

```
with(data = df1,
     expr = {
         data.frame(Value = rep(wrapr::seqi(min(Value), max(Value)), length(unique(ID))),
                    ID = unique(ID))
     }) %>%
    left_join(y = df1,
              by = c("ID" = "ID", "Value" = "Value")) %>%
    arrange(ID, Value)
```

#### Results

```
   Value ID freq
1      1  A    1
2      2  A   NA
3      3  A   NA
4      4  A   NA
5      5  A    5
6      1  B   NA
7      2  B    3
8      3  B   NA
9      4  B   NA
10     5  B    3
```

## Comments

- If I'm following your example correctly, your **`ID`** group takes values from 1 to 5. If this is the case, my approach would be to generate that reading unique combinations of both from the original data frame.
- The only variable that is carried from the original data frame is **`freq`** that may / may not be available for a given par **`ID-Value`**. I would join that variable via `left_join` *(as you seem to like `tidyverse`)*

  - In your example, you have **`freq`** variable with values 1,3,5 but then in the example you list 1,2,5? In my example, I took original **`freq`** and left join it. You can modify it further using normal `dplyr` pipeline, if this is something you intended to do.